# What testing frameworks can Chai be used with, aside from Mocha?

Tags: javascript, tdd, chai

Chai claims it "can be delightfully paired with any javascript testing framework".

Are there any others than Mocha that are in serious use?

Answer (score 0):

[Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) is probably the other most popular testing framework. In theory there is nothing stopping you using Chai assertions with Jasmine tests, but as Jasmine has its own built in assertion library then this is rarely done.

There are many other javascript testing frameworks (CasperJS and QUnit to name but two) all of which in theory it might be helpful to make assertions in using Chai. However, with the exception of Mocha, they normally have their own assertion functions and thus Chai is not required. The QUnit assertion library is somewhat limited so the addition of Chai may be helpful - it boils down to personal taste really.

The javascript testing tool chain is not as mature as that for other languages and it can be hard to navigate the various tools and find out which ones pair well with which others. My advice for beginners would be to not try any combinations of frameworks that have not been tried and tested before. Jasmine, or Mocha+Chai, are two perfectly serviceable options.

Comment: Thanks!

The reason I ask is that I have a Mocha+Chai test suite that I probably need to migrate to another framework.

Sounds like I should give Jasmine a look.